# Что делать с «требовательными» комментариями?

Tags: обсуждение, комментарии

Что делать с комментариями, которые нельзя назвать иначе, как
«требовательные»?  Например, комментарии типа «Не работает.  Напишите
рабочий ответ.» под ответом, «Вот скачате мой проект и найдите мне
ошибку.» под ответом, или «Приведите код!» под комментарием с ссылкой на
код (**не** под ответом!).

Эти ответы не обязательно грубые по форме, но содержат просьбы, которые
«вежливыми» тоже не назовёшь.  Флагать как «Что-то ещё»?  И что писать
в причину?

Comment: Игнорировать. 5 символов

Comment: @AK не согласен, лучше ответить. Сказав, что тут решают за вас проблемы типа *дебага*, а помогают разобраться.

Comment: 8321948713298417234 — вот номер карты для предоплаты. Остальное потом.

Comment: @edem просто и лаконично)

Comment: Я обычно отвечал «недостаточно информации, опишите вашу проблему подробнее отдельным вопросом» (но не добавлял «может, кто-то и ответит», хотя хотелось).

Comment: А на «скачайте мой проект и откомпилируйте» я честно говорил, что мне влом.

Comment: "Ой, дайте водички попить, а то так есть хочется, что даже переночевать негде...." :) Если в настроении - пишу что-то такого типа, если нет - игнорирую. А что еще сделаешь? Если человек сам не понимает...

Comment: @edem на подобное тут регулярно ругаются :(

Comment: @VladD случалось видеть в ответ на это заявления типа "И за что вам только деньги платят?!" Так я узнал, что часть пользователей думает, что отвечать - наша работа.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev А где зарплату получать, не говорили?...

Comment: @Harry наверняка в минобразования, учитывая количество школьников и студентов на ресурсе.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev это мог быть обычный стёб, про зп.

Comment: @edem не, человек был серьёзен, как сердечный приступ.

Comment: а что не так с «Не работает. Напишите рабочий ответ.» ?

Comment: @4per: «Не работает» не является описанием проблемы. По сути, «не работает» следует расшифровывать так: «У меня проблема, каким-то образом связанная с проблемой в вопросе (не скажу, каким именно). Я попробовал ваше решение (не скажу, с какими изменениями), и оно не дало ожидаемого результата. В чём именно ошибка (не компилируется? падает? делает не то, что надо? ломается другая часть программы?), вам следует угадать самостоятельно, и изложить мне здесь решение, которое будет работать для моего случая. Нет, про MCVE я ничего не слыхал.»

Comment: Если автор дал ответ, то у него работает. Требование угадать, в чём же неуказанный случай сердитого комментатора отличается от случая отвечающего — по сути требование прочитать мысли на расстоянии.

Comment: @VladD ну вообще не всегда, кто-то может написать ответ на тривиальный вопрос на коленке не запуская